# Kubuntu - 64 bit software on a 32 Bit OS

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a 32 Bit version of Kubuntu running on an old 64 Bit machine. Can I install 64 bit software on it, or does it have to be 32 bit?

Answer (score 1):

It would have to be 32bit as software is reliant on the OS. You would have to run a 64bit version of your OS to run 64bit software.

Answer (score 0):

You might *install* it (depends on your installation method) , but it would be *unuseable*.

If you want to *use* it, you'll need a 64 bit Kernel (e.g. -amd64, depending on your processor architecture) and maybe required to update some of the libs to its 64 Bit versions.

As far as i remember a simple `sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64` wouldn't do the trick ;/